# The best way to transform a response to a json format in the example

Tags: python, python-3.x

Appreciate if you could help me for the best way to transform a result into json as below.
We have a result like below, where we are getting an information on the employees and the companies. In the result, somehow, we are getting a enum like T, but not for all the properties.

```
  [  {
  "T.id":"Employee_11",
  "T.category":"Employee",
  "node_id":["11"]
},
{
  "T.id":"Company_12",
  "T.category":"Company",
  "node_id":["12"],
  "employeecount":800
},
{
  "T.id":"id~Employee_11_to_Company_12",
  "T.category":"WorksIn",
},
{
  "T.id":"Employee_13",
  "T.category":"Employee",
  "node_id":["13"]
},
{
  "T.id":"Parent_Company_14",
  "T.category":"ParentCompany",
  "node_id":["14"],
  "employeecount":900,
  "childcompany":"Company_12"
},
{
  "T.id":"id~Employee_13_to_Parent_Company_14",
  "T.category":"Contractorin",
}]
```

We need to transform this result into a different structure and grouping based on the category, if category in Employee, Company and ParentCompany, then it should be under the node_properties object, else, should be in the edge_properties. And also, apart from the common properties(property_id, property_category and node), different properties to be added if the category is company and parent company. There are few more logic also where we have to get the from and to properties of the edge object based on the '*to*' . the expected response is,

```
"node_properties":[
{
  "property_id":"Employee_11",
  "property_category":"Employee",
  "node":{node_id: "11"}
},
{
  "property_id":"Company_12",
  "property_category":"Company",
  "node":{node_id: "12"},
  "employeecount":800
},
{
  "property_id":"Employee_13",
  "property_category":"Employee",
  "node":{node_id: "13"}
},
{
  "property_id":"Company_14",
  "property_category":"ParentCompany",
  "node":{node_id: "14"},
  "employeecount":900,
  "childcompany":"Company_12"
}
],
"edge_properties":[
{
  "from":"Employee_11",
   "to":"Company_12",
  "property_id":"Employee_11_to_Company_12",
},
{
  "from":"Employee_13",
   "to":"Parent_Company_14",
  "property_id":"Employee_13_to_Parent_Company_14",
}
]
```

In java, we have used the enhanced for loop, switch etc. How we can write the code in the python to get the structure as above from the initial result structure. ( I am new to python), thank you in advance.

Regards

Comment: What have you tried in python? There is no problem to solve here.

Comment: can you please provide us the code on how I can get the response json from the result

Comment: I would be happy to give you the code if you are paying me for it. Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277140/5120049

Comment: Apologies for that, agreed, I was looking more for the best ways to achieve this, not for the full code

Comment: It would be great if you try doing it yourself like how you do in Java and if any problem or issue arises, ask a specific questions on that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that I quickly made, you can adjust it to your requirements. You can use regex or your own function to get the IDs of the `edge_properties` then assign it to an object like the way I did. I am not so sure of your full requirements but if that list that you gave is all the categories then this will be sufficient.

```
def transform(input_list):
node_properties = []
edge_properties = []
for input_obj in input_list:
    # print(obj)
    new_obj = {}
    if input_obj['T.category'] == 'Employee' or input_obj['T.category'] == 'Company' or input_obj['T.category'] == 'ParentCompany':
        new_obj['property_id'] = input_obj['T.id']
        new_obj['property_category'] = input_obj['T.category']
        new_obj['node'] = {input_obj['node_id'][0]}
        if "employeecount" in input_obj:
            new_obj['employeecount'] = input_obj['employeecount']
        if "childcompany" in input_obj:
            new_obj['childcompany'] = input_obj['childcompany']
        node_properties.append(new_obj)
    else: # You can do elif == to as well based on your requirements if there are other outliers
        # You can use regex or whichever method here to split the string and add the values like above

        edge_properties.append(new_obj)

return [node_properties, edge_properties]
```

Comment: thank you for your directions, I will check